# Form Data Refreshing Page Not Letting my JS run

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to run a script in my code when you click submit on a form but it wont run because the page resets but if i disable refresh none of the data is stored

ive tried disabling the refresh and thats about it

Comment: can you provide some snippet or more information exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your question correctly, but as I understand, you would like to prevent the page refresh on form submit and access the form's data.
You can do that with the preventDefault() method:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

So, let's say your form is the following:

```
<form action="" id="myForm" >
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

So, the first thing we want to do is to listen to the form submition by adding an event listener to the form:

```
const myForm = document.querySelector("#myForm");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
```

Then, we need to declare the function handleSubmit which takes the submition event as an argument, and we want to prevent it's default behaviour which is the page refresh:

```
function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

}
```

Then, the simplest way to access the data is by their ids, and we can do whatever it is we want with them:

```
function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const firstName = document.querySelector("#firstName").value;
    const lastName = document.querySelector("#lastName").value;

    const outputElement = document.querySelector("#outputElement");
    outputElement.textContent = "Hello " + firstName + lastName + ".";
}
```

I hope that's what you were looking for :)